# Why won't my first Vue component compile? / How to load vue-formio module?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, formio

I'm new to both Vue and Form.io, so there is something simple I'm missing here. I'm getting the error *"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-formio'"* in this Form.vue component:

```
<template>
  <formio src="https://rudtelkhphmijjr.form.io/demographics" v-on:submit="onSubmitMethod" />
</template>

<script>
import { Formio } from 'vue-formio';

export default {
  components: {
    formio: Formio
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmitMethod: function(submission) {
      console.log(submission);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This was an iteration of original Formio instruction that said "embed a form within your vue application, create a vue component using [this] formio component":

```
<template>
  <formio :src="formUrl" v-on:submit="onSubmitMethod" />
</template>
<script>
import { Formio } from 'vue-formio';

export default {
  data: function() {
    // Load these from vuex or some other state store system.
    return {
      formUrl: "https://rudtelkhphmijjr.form.io/demographics"
    }
  },
  components: {
    formio: Formio
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmitMethod: function(submission) {
      console.log(submission);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

But this too also returned the "Module not found: Error". Here is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Form />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Form from './components/Form.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Form
  }
}
</script>
```

I set up the basic project using Vue CLI and used npm install --save vue-formio before firing it up. Newbie help greatly appreciated!

I've also just noticed that vue-formio is not registered (as a dependency?) in package.json so perhaps that is related.

Comment: `import { Form } from 'vue-formio';...components: { formio: Form }` from [docs](https://github.com/formio/vue-formio)

Comment: Thx @depperm much appreciated. I tried this variation, but am not having any luck. Have also updated the question above to included the suggested Formio component they proposed to use. One thing that confuses me is that their code on github you shared is subtly different to the above instruction... in anycase neither are resolving vue-formio for me yet.

Comment: that code is from the github page directly [see](https://github.com/formio/vue-formio#basic-usage), did you attempt my change by changing the import from `{ Formio }` to `{ Form }` etc

Comment: Yeah, I did try that but to no avail yet

Comment: I'm going to dig more into verifying that vue-formio got installed, but I don't really understand much about this yet.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation `import { Form } from 'vue-formio';`
so you should replace your import on 6 line to `import { Form: Formio } from 'vue-formio';`